# Why is my IIS server receiving incorrect input from client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have just recently updated a web application on an IIS server, but after the update my users were receiving an incorrect input format error.  This error is because the code is trying to convert a user's string input into a double which obviously doesn't work if the user passes in something like 55.5D.

Besides the bad coding practice I'm going to fix anyway, that's not the real issue.  The issue is that the user was sending correct values (I watched and have input the exact same values myself) yet the program was still throwing this error.  I reverted back to a previous version and the error disappeared.  I haven't changed this section of code since the previous version.  Anybody know what is going on here?  I can't get the problem to repeat on development servers either without intentionally feeding the program bad input.

EDIT: I have tried clearing the user's and server's cache after the update, but that still received the same error, even after I put checks on the areas that were breaking (I missed some elsewhere in the code too).  However, it worked great when only a few users were using it at a time, but it was breaking when many users were using it.  Do ASP.NET controls have issues when many users are hitting the site?

Comment: Could be that it's holding onto the old DLLS and you need to do an application pool reset

Comment: @KSib I'm relatively new to IIS.  This is a precompiled site and I am replacing all of it's files with the new ones.  Does resetting the application pool clear a server side cache or something?

Comment: One of the things it does is recycles what's in memory so if you have something that's it's still holding onto, it should release it. If you notice this being an issue, I would always recycle the application pool after every deployment.

Comment: @KSib The changes were applied to the app after the update.  Are database values cached as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fully managed components in IIS do not require an application pool restart for changes to be applied. On the contrary, it will reload and JIT things again even if only web.config changes. If you are in doubt, you can always test this by including a test page with your application with a visible differentiator.

The most likely reason for your case is **caching**. Client-side is more likely culprit. Have you monitored http codes to verify that requests are really hitting your server and getting "live"-results (HTTP 200)?
Server-side in-process cache should be reset automatically but if you have persisted it somewhere out-of-process, they could be picked up after app upgrade..

And of course reverify that you really are testing exactly those dlls you think you are testing. If things don't make sense then verifying a wider set of assumptions can help.